# Merging two columns on value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Reproducible dataframe-

```
import pandas as pd
    
data = {'refid': ['1.2.34',
                     '1.2.35',
                     '1.3.66',
                     '1.6.99',
                     '1.9.00',
                     '1.87.66',
                     '1.98.00',
                     '1.100.1',
                     '1.101.3'],
             }
my_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([["A"]*6 + ["B"]*3, [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]], names=["ID-A", "ID-B"])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=my_index)
```

I want a new column which clubs both ID-B and refid to second delimiter.
ex- for ID-B 1 and refid 1.2.34, first the secondary-refid column should be 1.2 and unique ID should be 1_1.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and concatenate the values converted as string:

```
df['new'] = (df.index.get_level_values('ID-B').astype(str)+'_'
             +df['refid'].str.extract('(\d+\.\d+)', expand=False)
            )
```

output:

```
             refid      new
ID-A ID-B                  
A    1      1.2.34    1_1.2
     1      1.2.35    1_1.2
     1      1.3.66    1_1.3
     2      1.6.99    2_1.6
     2      1.9.00    2_1.9
     2     1.87.66   2_1.87
B    1     1.98.00   1_1.98
     1     1.100.1  1_1.100
     1     1.101.3  1_1.101
```

Comment: will it also create the col. secondary-refid 1.2 also? before the unique id.

Comment: @MemeFastKing no, it creates a single column, but you can first create `df['secondary-refid'] = df['refid'].str.extract('(\d+\.\d+)', expand=False)` then `df['unique ID'] = df.index.get_level_values('ID-B').astype(str)+'_'+df['secondary-refid']`

Comment: mozway the best!!